# Can "dynamic Ajax" exist? One that updates itself?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, session-variables

Is there a way to make ajax update its own code while executing? I work with sessions a lot and this would very much ease my job if it's possible. This is something like what I'm attempting to (unsuccessfully) do:

```
<!-- index.php (lots of code omitted) -->
<div id="ajax"><?php include 'ajax.php' ?></div>
```

and

```
<!-- ajax.php -->
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["test"])) $_SESSION["test"] = "not set";
else $_SESSION["test"] = "set";
?>

<script>
$('#somebutton').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            $('#ajax').html(result);
            $('#somediv').html('<?php echo $_SESSION["test"] ?>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

If what I'm trying to do is possible, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  Maybe you're looking to return two values from the server instead of one?  One value being the HTML content you want to add to the `#ajax` element, and the other being the content you want to add to the `#somediv` element?  You could potentially make two AJAX requests for those, or perhaps return both contents from the AJAX call as two strings on a JSON object.  Or maybe combine the two contents into a single response and separate them in the JavaScript code.

Comment: @David Two Ajax calls is probably what I'm looking at. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute a php server side script on a client who supports only javascript,html and css.

```
<?php echo $_SESSION["test"] ?>
```

This php code injected in the element won't ever execute, it's parsed like Html.
You need to make two ajax request to solve your problem.

You need to create another php file and do another ajax request to this.

For example the file could be:

**ajax2.php**:

```
<?php
start_session();
if(isset($_SESSION["test"))
    echo $_SESSION["test"] ;

?>
```

**javascript:**

```
$('#somebutton').click(function(){

   var ajaxCompleted = 0;
   var result1 = '';
   var result2 = '';

   //First call
   $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax.php',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(result){

           result1 = result;
           ajaxCompleted++;

           if(ajaxCompleted == 2){
               printResult();
           }
       }
   });

   //Second call
   $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax2.php',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(result){

           result2 = result;
           ajaxCompleted++;

           if(ajaxCompleted == 2){
               printResult();
           }

       }
   });

   function printResult(){
      $('#ajax').html(result1);
      $('#somediv').html(result2);
   }
});
```

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: That makes nothing but sense. Much appreciated.